# Alias a Command in Another Script

Tags: macos, bash, shell, unix, alias

I'm attempting to run a particular third party script (app.sh) that uses the maven command mvn. For day to day use and development I need mvn to map to version 3.1.1 (which is already done). But for this particular script to run I need to have version 3.0.5 of maven. I have the binary and necessary 3.0.5 files saved in /opt

In short, when app.sh is run, it runs the mvn command. When that script is run and when mvn is invoked in that script I need version 3.0.5 of maven to run. How can I accomplish this? Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try setting `mvn` alias to `3.0.5` version like this before running that script:

```
alias mvn='/opt/mvn-3.0.5/bin/mvn'
```

Change above alias to correct `mvn path` as needed.

2nd option is to change your `PATH` variable to put desired `mvn` binary before standard mvn as:

```
export PATH=/opt/mvn-3.0.5/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: I don't want to have to do that each time. Do you know if I can put this stuff into a shell script and execute it? Such as "startapp.sh" which does the exporting for me? Will the shell maintain the alias then?

Comment: Yes sure you can store any of my 2 suggested commands in your shell script.

Comment: The alias in the script. It resolved to the currently installed mvn (3.1.1)